# Logic error while trying to solve adventofcode day 4

Tags: java, logic-error

This is on day four of advent of code part two...
I tried out the sample input they gave and it was correct and I used the input I have and comes out wrong every time

[What I see 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtqhI.png)

[What I see 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMAZW.png)

There is more below but its what happens after you solve the first part

[Advent of code day 4](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/4)
[Puzzle input](https://pastebin.com/8kyQjjuF)

The input differs by user but the code should be the same no matter the input

- byr (Birth Year) - four digits; at least 1920 and at most 2002.
- iyr (Issue Year) - four digits; at least 2010 and at most 2020.
- eyr (Expiration Year) - four digits; at least 2020 and at most 2030.
- hgt (Height) - a number followed by either cm or in:
- - If cm, the number must be at least 150 and at most 193.
- - If in, the number must be at least 59 and at most 76.
- hcl (Hair Color) - a # followed by exactly six characters 0-9 or a-f.
- ecl (Eye Color) - exactly one of: amb blu brn gry grn hzl oth.
- pid (Passport ID) - a nine-digit number, including leading zeroes.
- cid (Country ID) - ignored, missing or not.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File inputText = new File("src/input.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputText);
        ArrayList<ArrayList> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList> attributes = new ArrayList<>();


        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String builtString = "";
            String input = "1";

            while(input.length() != 0 && sc.hasNextLine()) {
                input = sc.nextLine();
                builtString += input + " ";
            }
            String[] temp = builtString.split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> tempIds = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> tempAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String i : temp) {
                tempIds.add(i.split(":")[0]);
                tempAttributes.add(i.split(":")[1]);
            }
            ids.add(tempIds);
            attributes.add(tempAttributes);
        }
        System.out.println(ids);
        System.out.println(attributes);
        int valid = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < ids.size(); a++) {
            int has = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < ids.get(a).size(); j++) {
                String id = ids.get(a).get(j).toString();
                String attribute = attributes.get(a).get(j).toString();
                if (id.contains("ecl")) {
                    if (attribute.contains("blu") || attribute.contains("brn") || attribute.contains("gry") || attribute.contains("grn") || attribute.contains("hzl") || attribute.contains("oth")) {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " is an eye color");
                        has++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " is not an eye color");
                    }
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("pid")) {
                    if (attribute.length() == 9) {
                        try {
                            Integer.parseInt(attribute);
                            System.out.println(attribute + " of pid attribute is valid ");
                            has++;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(attribute + " of pid attribute is not valid");
                        }
                    }
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("eyr")) {
                    int at = Integer.parseInt(attribute);
                    if (at >= 2020 && at <= 2030) {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " attribute of eyr is valid");
                        has++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " attribute of eyr is not valid");
                    }
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("hcl")) {
                    boolean isValid = false;
                    if (attribute.contains("#")) {
                        for (char c : attribute.toCharArray()) {
                            if (attribute.length() == 7) {
                                if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || c == '#') {
                                    isValid = true;
                                } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                                    isValid = true;
                                } else {
                                    isValid = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (isValid) {
                        has++;
                    }
                    System.out.println(attribute + " hcl is " + isValid);
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("byr")) {
                    int date = Integer.parseInt(attribute);
                    if (date >= 1920 && date <= 2002) {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " byr attribute is valid");
                        has++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " byr attribute is not valid");
                    }
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("iyr")) {
                    int date = Integer.parseInt(attribute);
                    if (date >= 2010 && date <= 2020) {
                        has++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(attribute + " iyr is false");
                    }
                    has++;
                }
                if (id.contains("hgt")) {
                    boolean isValid = false;
                    String type = attribute.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
                    int amount = Integer.parseInt(attribute.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                    if (type.equals("in")) {
                        if (amount >= 59 && amount <= 76) {
                            isValid = true;
                            has++;
                        }
                    } else if (type.equals("cm")) {
                        if (amount >= 150 && amount <= 193) {
                            isValid = true;
                            has++;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(attribute + " hgt is " + isValid);
                    has++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (has >= 14) {
                valid++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(valid);
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Comment: Clicking "Puzzle input" link I get: *"Puzzle inputs differ by user.  Please log in to get your puzzle input."*

Comment: Fixed the input

Comment: Where are you getting all of these detailed validation rules? They don't appear in the problem statement linked.

Comment: I added a picture of what I see on the site I got them from the site link on day 4 https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/4

Comment: Its really hard to get the problem over to everyone because you have to log in to see the problem

Comment: You present a problem and code you think faulty. (How does *comes out wrong every time* manifest?) What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the 'amb' eye colour. If you add this to the if statement on line 41 it should work

```
if (attribute.contains("amb") || attribute.contains("blu") || attribute.contains("brn") || attribute.contains("gry") || attribute.contains("grn") || attribute.contains("hzl") || attribute.contains("oth")) {
```